# hive explain plan not showing partition

Tags: hive, hadoop-partitioning

I have a table which contains 251M records and size is 2.5gb.
   I created a partition on two columns which I am doing condition in predicate.
   But the explain plan is not showing it is reading partition even though I have partitioned. With selecting from partition column, I am inserting to another table.

Is there a particular order I have to mention the condition in predicate ?
How should I improve performance.

```
explain
  SELECT
              '123'                                                                         AS run_session_id
            , tbl1.transaction_id
            , tbl1.src_transaction_id
            , tbl1.transaction_created_epoch_time
            , tbl1.currency
            , tbl1.event_type
            , tbl1.event_sub_type
            , tbl1.estimated_total_cost
            , tbl1.actual_total_cost
            , tbl1.tfc_export_created_epoch_time
            , tbl1.authorizer
            , tbl1.acquirer
            , tbl1.processor
            , tbl1.company_code
            , tbl1.country_of_account
            , tbl1.merchant_id
            , tbl1.client_id
            , tbl1.ft_id
            , tbl1.transaction_created_date
            , tbl1.event_pst_time
            , tbl1.extract_id_seq
            , tbl1.src_type
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by tbl1.transaction_id ORDER BY tbl1.event_pst_time DESC)   AS seq_num       -- while writing back to the pfit events table, write each event so that event_pst_time populates in right way

          FROM db.xx_events tbl1                                --<hiveFinalDB>--                           -- DB variables wont work, so need to change the DB accrodingly for testing and PROD deployment
          WHERE id_seq     >= 215
             AND id_seq   <= 275
            AND vent        in('SPT','PNR','PNE','PNER','ACT','NTE');
```

Now how do I improve performance. The partition column is (id_seq,vent)

Answer (score 2):

`explain dependency select ...`

#### Demo

```
create table mytable (i int) 
partitioned by (dt date)
;
```

---

```
alter table mytable add 
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-18')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-19')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-20')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-21')
    partition (dt=date '2017-06-22')
;
```

---

```
explain dependency 
select  *
from    mytable
where   dt >= date '2017-06-20'
;
```

---

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                                            Explain                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"input_tables":[{"tablename":"local_db@mytable","tabletype":"MANAGED_TABLE"}],"input_partitions":[{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-20"},{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-21"},{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-22"}]} |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> "input_partitions":[
> {"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-20"},{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-21"},{"partitionName":"local_db@mytable@dt=2017-06-22"}]}