# How can i see which files were read in a hive query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-optimization, hiveql, hadoop2

I want to optimize a hive query. To do so I want to partition my table. To check if I have done everything right, I want to check, which files were read by hive to execute the query.
Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You mean, like `SELECT INPUT_FILE__NAME, a, b, c FROM wtf WHERE ... ?`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713424/6336479

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz had the answer i was looking for. Thank you :)